# Linq Search Between Two List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table schema like this:

MyTable columns:

```
 - FirstCol: 1507, 1507, 1507,1507,1507
 - SeconCol:  1508,1509,1510,1511,1512
```

I have a integer simple list of:

```
  List<int> myList= new List<int>();
             int a = 0;
             int myId= 1507;

            myList.Add(myId);

            foreach (var item in myList)
            {

                a = item.myId;
                myList.Add(a);

            }
```

It's result come like this :

```
 1507, 1508, 1509,1510,1511,1512(i am trying to get recursive query)
```

My second list of:

```
IEnumerable<Table> MyTable= table.SelectAll();
//myTable contains MyTableId, MyId, DeptId, UserId etc.
```

I just want to search if myTable's firstcol equals where ListmyList values. So here is my linq query with lambda expression.

```
 MyTable= MyTable.Where(myList.Contains((int)MyTable.Select(p=>p.myId))).ToList();
```

I get "Unknown methor where(bool) of. How can i change my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var result = MyTable.Where(x => myList.Contains(x.FirstCol)).ToList();
```

You can't use where clause like that, check [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) syntax.